# Spawning enemy in a new direction using xna

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

So in creating a tutorial using xna I learned to spawn sprites from the right side moving left using this code

```
Vector2 position = new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width +enemyTexture.Width / 2, random.Next(100, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height -100));
```

I wanted to change it so sprites would appear at the bottom and move to the top so I tried change it to this

```
Vector2 position = new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height + enemyTexture.Height / 2, random2.Next(100, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width - 100));
```

It kind of works but sometimes this results in the enemy spawning in the middle of the screen instead of the bottom. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Vector2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195795.aspx) structure asks for two parameters corresponding to the X and Y axis respectively.

You are setting your position in the wrong way by setting the X value to whatever is the bottom of the screen and the Y to "somewhere" on the screen by using random.

Try changing the order of the parameters like this:

```
Vector2 position = new Vector2(random2.Next(100, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width - 100), GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height + enemyTexture.Height / 2);
```

That way you are setting:

X = somewhere randomly along the X axis of the screen.
Y = The bottom of the screen - half the height of your sprint (are you sure you want to use half?).

Comment: Glad it worked, don't forget to mark the answer as "good" if everything works as expected now :)

Comment: I tried to upvote it. apparantly this requires better reputation. I clicked the checkmark.